Buildroot Raspberrypi 5 VCHI initializaion failed
I've done following using buildroot-2024.08:
make raspberrypi5_defconfig
make menuconfig 
enabled rpi-userland and other RPI related tools. 
make 

Then boot from sdcard, and execute:
# vcgencmd commands
VCHI initialization failed

Stock Raspberry PI OS - works well. What am I doing wrong?
Update:
The device /dev/vchiq is missing.
